# how to use if something in dataframe after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, if-statement

This is my code, that works until `df=pd.df`, and if I try to `print((df.loc[("invoice type")])` before the if, the code works, but when i use the if gives me the error `"Key Error: ´type´"`
when I `groupby` the column name type appears below the other columns.

What i need is to look for name type that contains words and number for example `invoice type-5` and print the value of column 2 only by using if to search that.

```
df = pd.read_excel("example.xlsx", header=0)
df = df.gropuby("type")[["column 2","column 3", "column 4"]].sum()

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

if "invoice type - 5" in df["type"]:
    print((df.loc[("invoice type")])
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(df)` what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't want to use `df[type]` - you want to use either `df['type']` (note the quotes) or `df.type`.

Secondly, you can check `if "your string" in df.your_column`. You need to use `df.your_column.str.contains("your string")` instead:

```
if df['type'].str.contains("invoice type - 5").any():
    print((df.loc[("invoice type")])
```

Comment: thanks richard. When i print my dataframe i get this columns in the same line: "Type" "Column 1", "Column 2" and "Column 3". But when i group the information by "Type", this title name goes one row down, and when i try to use "if "invoice type - 5" in df["Type"]" it brings me the error "Key Error: ´type´" like if a didnt define that. But if a do the same with the original data frame it doesnt bring me the error. How can i do to solve that error?

Answer (score -1):

Let's use `as_type=False` in groupby then `query` to filter the dataframe groupby results:

```
df.groupby('type', as_index=False)[["column 2","column 3", "column 4"]]\
  .sum().query('type == "invoice type - 5"')
```

MVCE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':np.random.choice([*'abcde'], 100),
                  'col1':np.random.random(100),
                  'col2':np.random.random(100)})

df.groupby('type', as_index=False)[['col1', 'col2']]\
  .sum().query('type == "a"')
```

Output:

```
  type      col1      col2
0    a  9.226583  8.052578
```